# Hbase store data in temp directory

Tags: java, hbase

I configured hbase-site.xml like this but data stores in temp directory.Why?

It's standalone.

```
 <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///usr/hbase/data</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks correct . Did you restart hbase ? Restarting is essential if you do any changes to the conf files. I checked on my system and it's working fine..
 By default hbase uses `/tmp/hbase-${user.name}` for storing data which I think is also being used in your case.

Comment: Hi.
Thanks.
Yes I restarted it.but it's config file in my IDEA(Intellij) And not in hbase conf directory.!Is it problem?